# How to prove cosine law using the power series expansion of cosine and sine?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, power-series

How to prove the equation $\cos(x + y) = \cos(x) \cos(y) -\sin(x) \sin(y)$ using the power series expansions
\begin{equation*}
   \cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}, \qquad \sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
\end{equation*}
I'm not getting further than that: multiplying the equations creates a very messy situation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can show us this messy situation, so we can constructively help with it. If you are afraid of typing out the full MathJax for your problem, it'll be difficult for you to get help

Comment: **Hint :** Define a function $e : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $e(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, then prove that $$e(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(ix)^n}{n!}$$ From that, prove that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $e(x+y)=e(x)e(y)$, and conclude.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks ! I am able to do this now. Earlier I was just substituting variables in power series expansion of cosine. This one is more efficient!